# How do you scale game difficulty with a curve?

Tags: math, scaling, calculus

I would just like to start by saying my calculus is terrible and I have next to no experience with using it.

I am trying to find an algorithm to help scaling in my game. Specifically it should scale the amount of waves that spawn per level. Ideally it will take any number as a level up to the max integer value. There would also be a minimum value and a maximum value that would be the minimum waves and maximum waves. So:

level = 0 to infinity
minValue = 3
maxValue = 40

result = an algorithm that will have a max curvature of the max value and shouldnt exceed it no matter what value the level is. I'm not sure how to calculate this but I think it would also need some kind of threshold that i could control to dictate the curvature based on the the level.

Comment: By "curvature" do you really mean [|y''|*(1+(y')^2)^(-3/2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean.

Comment: Okay, then what do you mean by curvature? Slope? Height? Second derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the next approach:

```
 mult = Min(1, (level/MaxLevel)**Somepower))
 minValue + (maxValue - minValue) * mult
```

Choose `Somepower` value suitable for your tasks. For example, value 2 gives parabola (note that value might be less than 1)

If you want more complex curve, show a picture of desired form.

Edit:

For the case when curve tends but does not become above some level, you can choose some function with horizontal asymptote. For example:

```
max * x /(x+1)
or 
max * arctan(k*x) * 2 / Pi
```

Comment: @joshstrike I assumed than minlevel=0 as author wrote.

Comment: I'm probably not explaining this well enough. In theory there is no max level, the max level is only there because of the maximum value of an int32. Basically I would want that for each level that it increases, the curve amount would increase less and less each time so that it never exceeds the maxValue. The minValue is probably irrelevant since I would just add it to the finished product that I want the algorithm to spit out

Comment: Yes, I felt that question is not stated well, but wanted to start discussion. In described case you can choose some function with horizontal asymptote. For example, `max* x /(x+1)` or `max* arctan(k*x)*2/Pi`